# How can I reduce the fade-in delay for panel-resizing sashes in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find the screen divider bar (sash) hard to grab in VS Code. The vertical divider bar to resize VS Code split window is very hard to locate with the mouse, because the mouse pointer does not change to double arrow, and the fade is too slow. You have to pause on top of 3 or 4 pixels to get the blue line to show.

Is there a setting to reduce the fade in delay for the vertical bar (sash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"workbench.sash.hoverDelay": 0,
```

The setting's description:

> Controls the hover feedback delay in milliseconds of the dragging area in between views/editors.

See also the `workbench.sash.size` setting.

Comment: Thats better.  i wish they had a mouse pointer switch on the "sash". did not know it was called a sash